# Use filename as list name using lapply and read_xls

Tags: r, list, filenames, lapply

I'm using `lapply` to read in multiple `.xls` files from a directory. Since the data represents data collected from sites with a different ID given by the filename, I'd like to set the list name to be the filename of each file.

I am currently doing the following:

```
library(readxl)

# Set filepath
file_location="FILEPATH"
# List all files within folder
filenames=list.files(file_location, pattern="^ID.*xls",full.names = T) 
# Import all files
import_data=lapply(filenames, function(x) read_xls(x, col_names = T))
```

I could then run something like this:

```
filenames_short=gsub(".xls", "", x=list.files(file_location, pattern="^ID.*xls",full.names = F))
names(import_data)=filenames_short
```

However, my pessimistic self is telling me that there is a possibility that the order of the filenames won't match the order of the list. Surely there must be a way to set this in the original command?

Comment: You are too pessimistic.

Comment: You're probably right, @jogo. Wishful thinking for there to be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @jogo, but if this generates insecurity, you can return the table with the name of the file.

One option is to add an attribute to the table:

```
import_data=lapply(filenames, function(x) {
                   out <- read_xls(x, col_names = T)
                   attr(out, "file") <- x
                   return(out)
                   })
```

Another is to return a list where the table is an object and it is already named.

```
import_data=lapply(filenames, function(x) {
                   out <- list(read_xls(x, col_names = T))
                   names(out) <- gsub(".xls", "", x)
                   return(out)
                   })
```